# "Possible duplicate" on both end?

Tags: discussion

There's a question [Why is Ubuntu named Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125321/why-is-ubuntu-named-ubuntu) which has a possible duplicate banner. It's a possible duplicate of the question [What does "Ubuntu" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424/what-does-ubuntu-mean), which itself is a duplicate of the first question.

This doesn't make any sense. I think there are more instances of this both end duplicacy. Why don't you guys form a little team and cross-check and tally all linked questions to remove such things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"which itself is a duplicate of the first question."

No, it is not? It has a comment about the 1st topic that is all. [What does "Ubuntu" mean?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424/what-does-ubuntu-mean) is the to go question about the meaning of Ubuntu. But is not marked as a duplicate; it is just a "protected" question.

As with all comments, if they are obsolete (as in this case) - just flag and one of your friendly mod/janitors will tidy up - as has been done in this case.